# In WPF, how do I use multiple textboxes to validate the data of another textbox, and vice versa?

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

On my UI, I have four textboxes. They represent the red, green, blue, and hex values for a given color. I would like for a few things to happen:

When the text for the red, green, *or* blue textboxes gets changed, I want to validate/update the text in the hex textbox to make sure it stays valid given the new RGB values.

Conversely, if the user edits the hex value directly, I would like the RGB values to also update.

I tried making two `TextChanged` handlers. One went off if red, green, or blue got changed and updated the hex value. The other went off if the hex value was changed, and it updated the RGB values. The problem with this approach, I discovered, was that I ran into recursion (since they were changing each other and re-calling the `TextChanged` events again).

I'm still new to WPF, so from here, I'm not sure where to look. What is the best way to synchronize/validate these textboxes in a 3-to-1 (and vice versa) manner?

Comment: You will want to use validation rules probably. Try sticking with MVVM design too, it'll make life much easier. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation) is a start.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I was reading it over, and then derailed into reading through several pages/tutorials on MVVM. I hadn't heard of it, yet. This is just a small practice project for me, so I think I'll take the time to refactor everything to try and make the focus of the project learning MVVM. That being said, though, I do have a question - if I put some validation rules in for the `set` of each item, won't they still be recursively calling each other? (i.e. if I check on/validate the RGB values when Hex gets changed, that might change the RGB values which in turn will check/set the Hex.)

Comment: Sounds like that is what would happen.  One solution could be that, you use a separate value for your Hex code, and in the setter you validate the value, if its valid you set the RGB values, if its not, don't set the RGB values.  Same goes for RGB values to Hex.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying... Instead of just updating them in the setters, checking first to see if they _need_ it, and then only updating if necessary. It definitely _sounds_ like a better idea. I'll give that a shot after I've worked on refactoring for MVVM. Thanks! If you formulate that into an answer, I'll accept it for this question.